# Datatable reloading after clicking the commandLink in the header section

Tags: jsf-2

I am little new to JSF. I have a question regarding the datatable  and eventhandling. Here is the scenario what I want to do. 
I have datatable which Priority,id, address, and phone number and a backing bean is Person.I have to sort Priority column based on 3 values Critical, Warning, Low. I have sorted the priority column using Comparator stuff. Its working fine.
Now, the challenge for me is once the records are sorted in the managed beans, I want to populate the datatable with the updated sorted results. The records are ArrayList.

```
<p:column>
                <f:facet name="header" >
                     <h:commandLink action="#{personManagedBean.sortByPriority}">
                        Pririty
                   </h:commandLink>
                </f:facet>
                #{person.priority}
</p:column>
```

In the managed bean,

```
public class PersonManagedBean{

private ArrayList<Person> personList;

//getters and setters for personList.

public String sortByPriority(){
    Collections.sort(personList, new PersonComparator());
    return null;
}
}
```

Once the Collections.sort line is executed, I want to populate the datatable with the sorted personList records.

Can you guys please assist me in that?

Thank You.

Comment: The given code should already do that, unless you're incorrectly retrieving the data from DB in the getter method instead of the (post)constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you still can modify your existing code to work too by adding `<f:ajax render="@form"/>` into your `<h:commandLink`

like this

```
 <h:commandLink action="#{personManagedBean.sortByPriority}">
     <f:ajax render="@form"/>
     Priority
  </h:commandLink>
```

You better use the `sortBy` and the `sortFunction` of p:column

This is how it should look like (notice the additional use of `<h:outputText value="` which is better than simple text)

```
<p:column sortBy="#{person.priority}" sortFunction="#{personManagedBean.sortByPriority}">
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <h:outputText value="Priority">
    </f:facet>
       <h:outputText value="#{person.priority}"/>
</p:column>
```

and this is how the `sortByPriority` should look like (more or less)

```
public int sortByPriority(Object Obj1, Object Obj2) {

    if (Obj1 != null && Obj2 != null) {

        //turn the Objects into Strings or some other objects

        return newObj1.compareTo(newObj2);

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

take a look at the showcase example [DataTable - Sorting](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSorting.jsf)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the solution